# setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) vs getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu)

Tags: java, android, inflate

Why do I have to tell my activity what its layout should be twice?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // <--
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu); // <--
    return true;
}
```

What's the difference between these two methods?. when should I use one, and when the other?

Comment: first one for Activity window and second for OptionsMenu

Comment: The `R.layout` and `R.menu` are the key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are two separate things. The names tell you. `R.layout.activity_main` is your layout, `R.menu.activity_main` is for your **menu**.

`setContentView()` sets the layout for the Activity. It includes Buttons, TextViews, etc.

`onCreateOptionsMenu()` makes the menu that you see when you press the menu key or it populates the ActionBar on Android 3.0+.

They do two completetly separate things. `setContentView()` is often needed (unless you have an empty `Activity`), `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is optional, depending on if you need to show more options.

Comment: I see. and by "menu" you mean this -> https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQrVPCPADkO2xtE_33ELya-evX_fEmXPJZ3n3TnOm-PdY38zGiEIw   ?

Comment: However, when you create a Fragment, you DO Use the inflater. how come?. why can't I use setContentView for those as well?

Comment: You're talking about `getView()` in fragments. That's because Fragments don't have a `setContentView()` method. However note that it doesn't use `getMenuInflater()`, but instead a `LayoutInflater`. Both inflate, but `LayoutInflater` is for layouts.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it.. Thanks. I'm just picking up Android programming and it's pretty confusing so far. I really appreciate it!.

Comment: @user1949554: no problem! if you could check the hollow checkmark besides my answer (to accept this answer) it would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

java file inside the gen folder there will be defined layout, ID and menu static class. you will get the idea from there.